# compilation.errors.push(new webpack_1.WebpackError(message))

Tags: angular12

After upgrade to Angular12 facing an issue like
compilation.errors.push(new webpack_1.WebpackError(message));
Inside node_modules@ngtools\webpack\src\webpack-diagnostics.js:17
TypeError: webpack_1.WebpackError is not a constructor
at Object.addError (\node_modules@ngtools\webpack\src\webpack-diagnostics.js:17:29))
at \node_modules@ngtools\webpack\src\ivy\diagnostics.js:19:39
at AngularWebpackPlugin.updateAotProgram(\node_modules@ngtools\webpack\src\ivy\plugin.js:342:17)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same issue and found out that the peer dependency of webpack@^5.0.0 was missing when running "npm list".

I fixed it by adding webpack to my project:
https://www.npmjs.com/package/webpack